# Use component inner component html template as top level

Tags: angular

Edit: I want to basically hide the "app-some-component" from generating at the top level, and only render the inner HTML of that component.

If I define a component with template like this:

```
<div>Top level div</div>
```

and reference it like this somewhere else

```
<app-some-component></app-some-component>
```

is it possible for

```
<div>Top level div</div>
```

...to be what is rendered only as the parent and not the tag generated by the "app-some-component"?

Thank you

Comment: no. I dont understand why that is a problem. Effectively you are trying to hide the `app-some-component` element from the DOM.

Comment: If what you described is what OP meant, there might be a number of reasons why OP wants to "hide it" (or just ignore it) - for instance having the `<div>` be considered in CSS as a direct child of the parent component, ignoring the host element (which is possible). That said, it's not clear at all what exactly they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: that is correct I want to hide the app-some-component. This is possible in other frameworks I've used. I am wondering if it's possible to do so in angular

Comment: the reason is that the app-some-component element will not work well with the HTML/CSS structure, so I want to ignore it. Just want to know if it's possible and how to go about it, otherwise I'll just work around it somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In component decorator use:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-some-component]', // instead of ‘app-some-component’
  … 
})
```

In parent component template use:

```
<div app-some-component></div>
```

In app-some-component template just use:

```
Top level div
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the <div> is actually another component such as <app-special-div> ?