# How remove angular selector in ng-content

Tags: angular, ng-content

I have this imbrication of component

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <app-form-field label="Input" [required]="true" [control]="form.controls['input']">
      <app-input formControlName="input"></app-input>
    </app-form-field>
  </form>
```

this is a render of the DOM:
[image]

How can i remove the app-input angular selector and just keeping input tag please?

I need this for works with ~ or > css operator

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the `<app-input>` selector, but there may be other solutions to your problem:

- If you don't actually have any logic in `<app-input>` that you need, just replace this with a native `<input>`. `formControlName` will work on native `<input>` tags out of the box (as long as you have imported the `ReactiveFormsModule`), you don't always need a component
- If you do have a need for the `app-input` component

  - Use classes on descendent elements instead of `>` or `~` to specifically target the elements you want to style no matter how they are nested

  ```
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <app-form-field>
      <app-input formControlName="input" class="form-control"></app-input>
    </app-form-field>

    <app-form-field>
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="input2" class="form-control" />
    </app-form-field>

    <input type="radio" formControlName="input3" class="form-control" />
  </form>
  ```

  - Use a combination of selectors, e.g.

  ```
  form app-form-field > *,
  form app-form-field app-input input {
    // your style
  }
  ```

Comment: Please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74923625/16396735 I guess it’s you need.